# Amazon Elastic IP issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've read a lot of questions already posted on this topic but none seem to provide an answer that helps, so forgive me for the duplicate post if I missed one...

I setup an elastic beanstalk single instance application. I then ensure'd the EC2 instance that it spawned had a security group to allow port 80 incoming requests. I then created an elastic ip and associated the EC2 instance with the ip, but neither the public dns or the elastic ip will respond to http requests.

Any ideas why this might be an issue for me?

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was, even though I'd associated my elastic IP to my instance and created firewall rules in new security groups to provide access, ***I hadn't associated my new security groups with my instance***.  To fix this, I used the *Change Security Groups* menu from my *Instances* screen:

[image]

This caused the following popup to appear, where, sure enough, my new security groups existed but weren't *associated* with my instance:

[image]

After I (1) checked the appropriate boxes and (2) clicked on *Assign Security Groups*, all was well.

Answer (score 1):

In classic-EC2 scenario:

1. Make sure port 80 is allowed in your AWS security group.
2. Make sure port 80 is allowed in local operating based firewall on your system. OR disable the local firewall for the time being to narrow down the issue.
3. Make sure that your application is indeed `listening` on port 80. You can check this by running `telnet 127.0.0.1 80`.

If above 3 points are satisfied, I don't see a reason why you are not able to access your application on port 80.

Let us know in case you are using VPC and not classic-EC2.

BTW, when you attach elastic IP, the instance will drop the public DNS that it had earlier. So now you should work with elastic IP only.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a case where the elastic IP address was itself not responding on a  specific port number.  When I associated the instance with a different elastic IP, everything worked fine.  So I resolved the issue by allocating a new elastic IP address.  **Root cause:** Amazon evidently does not have an effective internal process for validating the integrity of an elastic IP.  Obviously that's a tall order considering the things outside their control that can happen, with denial of service attacks and etc.

It cost me a day of doing progressive isolation to get to this, which I would have never otherwise suspected.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance there is also a firewall running on the machine? I know in windows I usually need to open the port on the windows firewall AND on amazon's security.

Comment: Firewall running on my local machine or on amazon? Port 80 is open on amazon security group, on my machine i run no firewall.

Comment: Perhaps the server is running iptables or some other firewall variant. You need to check if there is something system level blocking the connection.